# leaflet set rectangle coordinated from mouse events

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, leaflet

I'm trying to allow the user to be able to set one corner of a rectangle to draw on the mouse down event, when the mouse up event triggers i'd like to set the opposing corner coordinates and draw the rectangle. I have tried the following in my *.ASPX javascript:

```
var oneCorner;
var TwoCroner;

map.on('mousedown', setOneCorner);
map.on('mouseup', setTwoCorner);

function setOneCorner(e)
{
    oneCorner = e.latlng;
}

function setTwoCorner(e)
{
    twoCorner = e.latlng;
    var bounds = [oneCorner.latlng, twoCorner.latlng];
    L.rectangle(bounds, {color:"#ff7800", weight:1}).addTo(map);
}
```

my tiles can still pan on the mouse down event but I'd like to be able to draw a rectangle where ever i want. how should i go bout doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you dont want your map to pan., then you can add 
`map.dragging.disable()`
to your code. Also your array with bounds should be `var bounds = [oneCorner, twoCorner];`
because corners variables are already LatLng objects.

Full code would be:

```
var oneCorner;
var TwoCroner; 

map.on('mousedown', setOneCorner);
map.on('mouseup', setTwoCorner);

map.dragging.disable();

function setOneCorner(e)
{
oneCorner = e.latlng;
} 

function setTwoCorner(e)
{
twoCorner = e.latlng;    
var bounds = [oneCorner, twoCorner];
L.rectangle(bounds, {color:"#ff7800", weight:1}).addTo(map);
}
```

But I dont think its good idea to prevent map pan. What about to use it with Ctrl, or you can use this plugin for drawing: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw

// EDIT:

Version with only Ctrl pressed.:

```
var oneCorner;
var TwoCroner; 

map.on('mousedown', setOneCorner);
map.on('mouseup', setTwoCorner);

function setOneCorner(e)
{
    if (e.originalEvent.ctrlKey) {
        map.dragging.disable();
        oneCorner = e.latlng;   
    }    
} 

function setTwoCorner(e)
{
    if (e.originalEvent.ctrlKey) {
        twoCorner = e.latlng;    
        var bounds = [oneCorner, twoCorner];
        L.rectangle(bounds, {color:"#ff7800", weight:1}).addTo(map);        
    }
    map.dragging.enable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about using the Ctrl button after I posted but not sure where/how I would check for the key pressed, do u know where?

Comment: Also, could checking for the Ctrl button press be achieved without using the plugin? I want to avoid licensing issues

Comment: Luckily there is variable in `e.originalEvent` which checked pressed Ctrl. So, yes. It's pretty easy to implement. Check my edit.